sum cells in a row if two text cells match in separate columns
I have multipul columns of names in sheet1(I1:I) and also multipul columns of names in sheet2(A1:A), sheet2 also contains 12 months of sales quantities in corresponding columns (R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC)
Im trying to sum the total value of the twelve monthes if a name in sheet1 is matching a name in sheet2.

Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. Sheet1!I1:I and Sheet2!A1:A each signify one column of multiple rows. Please [edit] your question and add a table of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results.

Use filter(), like this:
=sum(filter(Sheet1!R$2:AC, Sheet2!A$1:A = I1))

See filter().
